# How do I use the authentication token received from VSO API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've written a Node app that allows me to authenticate with Visual Studio Team Services (using Microsoft Account). I know I'm successfully able to login with my organization account (i.e. joe@**contoso.com**) because I receive an access token and profile information, such as my name and email address.

When I try to use the access token with an API call to VSO (using the bearer token strategy), I receive a 401 error from the service with the following message.

`TF400813: The user 'Windows Live ID\00030000BE8767F8@Live.com'; is not authorized to access this resource.`

It seems like the account embedded in the access token is not the one I signed in with, which is super confusing. Anyone know what's going on here?

FWIW, I'm trying to make a work item query request.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with how I was passing the POST body. I don't think that should have resulted in a 401, but once I fixed it my call is working as expected. Unrelated to VSO API.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's an old topic, but for those coming here from google.
It depends how you set the access token for your credentials on subsequent calls.

The following did the trick for me.

```
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://youraccountname.visualstudio.com"), new VssOAuthCredential("accessToken"));
var client = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var projects = client.GetProjects().Result;
```

Comment: What type of value is represented by the "accessToken" variable in your example? If I just replace "accessToken" with the token received during the authorization process, as a string, I get the error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'grant'..."

Answer (score 0):

Wesley van Heije is almost right (*I cannot comment on his answer due to not enough reputation*). The updated code that works for me in case of oauth2 access token is:

```
VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential credentials = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(AccessToken);
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/[your org]"), credentials);
var client = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var projects = client.GetProjects().Result;
```

Thanks to answer number 2 from [here](https://living-sun.com/c/125823-how-do-i-use-the-vsts-oauth2-bearer-token-provided-by-the-authorization-routine-c-oauth-20-vsts-vsts-api.html) for finding this needle in the haystack.